# How to increment the counter value when the input field is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

This is my `laravel` view code. Here,I am trying to increment the counter value(ie.,value="0/5") . I have the input fields inside the modal and when clicking on the save button which is inside the model, the value should get incremented based on the filled input fields.ie(1/5..2/5..)

I have tried to increment those counter value.But it displays **NaN**

```js
var val;
$("input").click(function() {
  val = $('#counter').val();
  val++;
  $('#counter').prop('value', val)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-title pull-left">
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:20px;color:lightgreen">
     </i> Price,stock and Shipping Information<input type="submit" id="counter" value="0/5" style="background-color: transparent; border:none">
</div>
```

Comment: Change the value attribute from "0/5" to "0" and try it again.

Comment: That works!! but I want it as 0/5 and need to replace '0' by the counter value

Comment: You means 0 out of 5?

Comment: yes sir,the same

Comment: You are already doing it in the wrong way. You are a programmer think on it don't just write like a typewriter.

Comment: What am I doing wrong.Will u mention it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input").click(function() {
        let val = parseInt($('#counter').val().split('/')[0]);
        $('#counter').prop('value', `${++val}/5`);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry,no increment takes place

Comment: my mistake, have a try again.

Comment: if you want to make 0-5 works as a carousel, just replace ${++val} to ${++val % 6}.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is working fine. Since you have the view inside a modal, which is only displayed or shown on a click event, you should use the jQuery "**on**" method to enhance your click handler function definition. In that case you should have your code working

```js
var val;
$(document).on('click','#counter',function()
{
   val = $('#counter').val();
   val++;
   $('#counter').prop('value',val )
});
```

```html
 <div class="panel-title pull-left">
 <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:20px;color:lightgreen">
 </i>
 Price,stock and Shipping Information<input type="submit" id="counter" 
 **value="0/5"** style="background-color: transparent; border:none">
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your code wont work if value is something else then 0/5 for example 5/15

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to parse data before `/` character

```
var val;
$("input").click(function() {
  val = $('#counter').val();
  qty = val.match(/[^/]*/i)[0];
  qty++;
  $('#counter').prop('value', qty)
});
```

Comment: It replaces the value totally. I just want to incremet like this 1/5.2/5

Comment: you said increment value so I incremented it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase like this `1/5..2/5` .Use `split` and increase only upper value .

```js
var val;
$("input").click(function() {
  val = $('#counter').val().split("/");
  //check eqal value with base
  if(val[0] == val[1]) {
   return false;
  }
  val[0]++;
  
  $('#counter').prop('value', val[0]+"/"+val[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-title pull-left">
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:20px;color:lightgreen">
     </i> Price,stock and Shipping Information<input type="submit" id="counter" value="0/5"  style="background-color: transparent; border:none">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
$("input").click(function() {
    var val = $('#counter').val();
    $('#counter').prop('value', `${++val % 6}/5`);
});
```

And a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wv2x0mx5/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```js
$("#counter").on("click",function(){
  var counterBtn = document.getElementById("counter");
  var count = counterBtn.value;
  //alert(count.split("/")[0]);
  count = count.split("/");
  counterBtn.value = ((parseInt(count[0])+1)%(parseInt(count[1])+1))+"/"+count[1];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-title pull-left">
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="font-size:20px;color:lightgreen">
     </i> Price,stock and Shipping Information<input type="submit" id="counter" value="0/5" style="background-color: transparent; border:none">
</div>
```